# Error no such file or directory

Tags: programming, executable, execute-command

I have this executable file in my folder and whenever I try to execute it, it shows the error

```
sudo: unable to execute ./GASS_NCBI: No such file or directory
```

After typing

```
ls -alt
```

This is what shows up

```
total 1156
drwxrwxrwx 6 root root   4096 Dez 20 18:47 templates
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root   4096 Nov  1 09:43 .
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root   4096 Nov  1 09:43 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  43007 Nov  1 09:43 GASS
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  29694 Nov  1 09:43 GASS.cpp
-rw------- 1 root root  39656 Nov  1 09:43 GASS.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 578340 Nov  1 09:43 2ocj.pdb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2158 Nov  1 09:43 quebra_cadeia.pl
-rw-r----- 1 root root   1062 Nov  1 09:43 GeraTemplateNCBI.pl
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov  1 09:43 pdbs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    142 Nov  1 09:43 execucao.txt
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 Nov  1 09:43 old
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2876 Nov  1 09:43 pdb_to_txt.pl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   4358 Nov  1 09:36 ActiveSitesFound.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    384 Nov  1 09:36 .run_weka_prediction.pl.kate-swp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    147 Nov  1 09:36 AtomoMaisPesado.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2160 Nov  1 09:36 filter_lha.pl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  29784 Nov  1 09:36 GASS_NCBI.cpp
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  29781 Nov  1 09:36 GASS_NCBI.cpp~
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     15 Nov  1 09:36 pdbs.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1274 Nov  1 09:36 split_chain.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    473 Nov  1 09:36 pdb.pl
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3316 Nov  1 09:36 preprocessing.cpp
-rw------- 1 root root 159523 Nov  1 09:36 TemplatesCSA_LIT.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     92 Nov  1 09:36 compile.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    987 Nov  1 09:36 format_fitness.pl
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  36677 Nov  1 09:36 GASS_NCBI
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14806 Nov  1 09:36 preprocessing
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 116705 Nov  1 09:36 ..sst
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   1077 Nov  1 09:36 teste.pl
```

I've run the command

```
chmod +x GASS_NCBI
```

and I run it by typing

```
sudo ./GASS_NCBI
```

Any idea of what is happening?

Comment: Please add the outputs of `file GASS_NCBI` and `ldd GASS_NCBI`

Comment: This type of error occurs hwen you try to run an 32bit executable on a 64bit system.

Comment: For `file GASS_NCBI` is `GASS_NCBI: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=96e5a806c2edd7d8dfa22dfc09096a6bef08e386, not stripped`

Comment: For `ldd GASS_NCBI` is `not a dynamic executable`

Comment: Like @solsTiCe pointed out, the `file` and `ldd` outputs suggest you are trying to run a 32-bit executable on a 64-bit OS without the necessary additional 32-bit libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could install programs like strace, and it's family of tools. That way you could run 'strace ./GASS_NCBI' and see all the library calls being made to see if it is just choking on something.

Comment: I did, here is the result `execve("./GASS_NCBI", ["./GASS_NCBI"], [/* 22 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "strace: exec: No such file or di"..., 40strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++`

Comment: Its a very messy program, but basically it is saying that the file your program is trying to write to does not exist. I am not sure what your code says or is doing. This is just a tool to narrow down the issue.